# Nvidia 520MX graphics card on Asus K53SC

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-prime

I'm sorry if it is possibly a double post, but I could not find a solution anywhere.
I have tried over and over again to install Nvidia driver on my Ubuntu 13.10 laptop, considering that it should be fairly easy with optimus (and considering that I never succeeded using bumblebee), but once I install them and restart the machine, there are A LOT of system errors and the visual effects are completely gone (even though the system recognizes my exact graphic card) And I have to install them because if I don't my PC overheats..

what can I do?

The command I used is:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

and after that it all goes to waste.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

13.10 comes with official bumblebee support. Go to software center and search `bumblebee`.
[image]
After installing this click in more info and check all 3 add-ons then click apply changes.[image]
After that your bumblebee is installed with nvidia driver.

Now If you want to configure Bumblebee indicator then Follow these:

Install Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Make a directory for git:

```
mkdir git and cd git
```

Check out the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
cd bumblebee-ui
sudo ./INSTALL
```

Go to Startup Applications and add `/usr/local/bin/bumblebee-indicator`

Now reboot again.